# How can we add Page builder with custom form without Eav attribute and Ui component

Tags: magento2, page-builder

How can we add Page builder with custom form without Eav attribute and Ui component. Is there any way to include page builder in ***`$form->addField().`***

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution ?